# What is Best way to redirect www.example.com to example.com

Tags: php, .htaccess

hope you people doing well ! what will be Best way to redirect www.example.com  to  example.com.

I have used .htaccess ,but its giving me problem in Jquery POST call ..

So now i am confused which method i can use for redirecting www

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can't 301 redirect a POST request without losing the request's body, which is probably why you're getting jquery errors. You can either ensure jquery requests have the "www." in the hostname removed, or you only redirect for `GET` or `HEAD` requests:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} (GET|HEAD)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: Thanks , i am trying this one :)

Comment: @SSK: Please make sure to accept the answers that solve your problems, by clicking on the check mark next to the answer.